# MS Exchange: User who can check 'OutOfOffice' settings of other users,

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010

I am a developer, & have minimum knowledge of server or serverfalut. Do tell me if this is not right the forum to this question.

I have a java program which checks 'OutOfSettings' of the user. I am using EWS.

Currently I can check 'OutOfOffice' settings of the user who is authenticated with the service. When I try to access 'OutOfOffice' setting of other users, I get 'Access Denied'.
No wonder, I am using normal user(not some sort of admins).

Question:- Is it possible to configure a admin or super user who can see 'outofoffice' settings of all(or at least listed) users. It will be great if the said user can only do that much.

Very high level note on how can this be achieved will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OutOfOffice settings are private to the user mailbox and is not exposed for impersonated sessions in EWS.

What you need is [`MailTips`](http://windowsitpro.com/outlook/q-what-are-mailtips-used-exchange-2010-outlook-2010)! With Exchange 2010, applications can fetch information about things like Free/Busy information for user calendars and Out of Office settings (Outlook 2010 already does this).

[Glen Scales has posted an actual example on his blog, documenting how you can retrieve the OutOfOffice settings MailTip for a mailbox](http://gsexdev.blogspot.dk/2011/11/using-mailtips-in-ews-to-get-oof-out-of.html)